# format() function is always returning "0.00"

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

I have some calculation that I am running that would provide a double/float back:

```
a = float(4)
b = float(56100)
c = a / b
```

Now when run the script, I get this:

`7.1301e-05`

I just need to format this response so that I get `7.13`. But when I try to do this I get `0.00`:

```
percentage_connections_used = float(a) / float(b)
percentage_float = float(percentage_connections_used)
print(format(percentage_float, '.2f'))
```

I can't seem to figure out why it would return 0 when trying to format it. Can someone possibly tell me what is going on? This is Python 2.7

Comment: Why would you expect to get 7.81, when it's 0.000078125?

Comment: actually this is the correct behaviour, as 7.8125e-05 is 0.000078125 which will become 0.0 when you round off

Comment: Then you'll need to multiply by 10,000.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense. I will recheck my math :-)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: No, it's probably not.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Op is only interested in the first few digits of the significand. A 32 bit float generally has at least 7 digits of accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your format is correct, but when you try to round to 2 decimal places It actually rounds to 0.00.

7.8125e-05 = 0.000078125

When rendered as 2 decimals, you get 0.00.

You could do a little string manipulation to parse out the 7.8125 figure by using:

```
d = float(str(c).split('e')[0])
```

It's a little verbose, though, and maybe someone in the community can do better.

By the way, I get 7.1301...e-05 when I run a/b.

Answer (score 1):

`7.8125e-05` is the same as `0.000078125` so formatting it with only two decimal points gives you `0.00`.  You could do `'.7f'` which would get you 0.0000713.  If you want it to output in scientific notation, you should do that explicitly.  Try this:

```
a = float(4)
b = float(56100)
c = a / b

print("{:.2e}".format(c))
```